# A user changes a large number of posts by inserting the name of a commercial product

Tags: support, spam

[One of the users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614494/filip26) changes a large number of posts by inserting the name (and/or web links) of a commercial product [DHC by Restlet](https://restlet.com/products/dhc/) (for example here: [Store information on client using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22686648/3901618) and in some other posts). I can't flag it as a spam, because the original post wasn't a spam.

Comment: The two that I just looked at were not _insertion_: the mention of the product -- _and_ the link -- were already there. As the edit summary says, he's _correcting_ the name and link.

Comment: This is the first one I've found where the link was added: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11108526

Comment: @JoshCaswell "Dev HTTP Client" has been changed to "DHC" twice with the comment: "fix grammar errors"

Comment: @JoshCaswell Here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21992612/revisions

Comment: Some of these are name changes, some are adding links. I really dislike the way the change the name, "DHC *by Restlet Download*". Too marketing-y.

Comment: I've notified the user about this meta discussion on one of their own posts (now self-deleted) on the product: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21992612/3155639

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that's cause for alarm here, necessarily...The product link at first blush seems to have changed, and the edits are correcting that change.  I will *happily* admit that the description for it does seem a bit over the top, though.  Correcting the link would've been enough.

Comment: I'm developing DHC for four years, for free. Now we have added a new cool features and changed product name. All features provided before that stay for free.

Comment: The user has also created a tag for the product: [tag:dhc]

Comment: @filip26 To avoid suspicion, when you do something like this, you should post on meta about it first. We can be prone to paranoia at times.

Comment: What's wrong on putting links on a tool which is for free that someone else recommended? Isn't that just a help for a user to find it?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara:  I'm not sure I'm seeing a problem...the usage of the tag seems to be in-line with other tooling that we've got on the site.  Everyone should probably chill out and assume good intentions instead of malice.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't say it was a problem, or not, just adding for reference.

Comment: @filip26 the biggest part of the problem is that you're doing a large number of edits without asking if the community is ok with the changes. You would probably not have had a problem if you had come to meta first and let us know what you planned to do.

Comment: @TinyGiant OK, a message received, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the only real problem I'm observing is that the questions aren't been thoroughly edited.  It's fine to fix the link, but while you're there, why not take a moment to fix as much as you can with the post?

Outside of this...I'm not seeing an issue here.  We can keep an eye on it to be sure nothing gets out of hand.  Hopefully the editor would let us know in the future when they decide to do something like this...the folks on Meta <s>can</s> get antsy <s>at times</s>.

Comment: I think people wouldn't have been so suspicious if the *by Company* had been omitted from the edit.

Comment: IMO, the "by Company" part but should not be added unless the original post had this bit and it needs updating. Too marketing-y, and it doesn't really add anything of value.